# Elasticsearch or Ravendb for analytics data

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, analytics, ravendb

I'm creating a custom web analytics for my application, with very specific inputs of user data. Basically, I'm writing all the user interaction on the website (page visited, banner click, button click, etc), so this will generate tons of data and inserts per second. This software will be connected to a signalr hub and the administrator will see some realtime statistics.

Our first choice was use RavenDb (better .NET integration) and the triggers can easy connect the events to signalR, but my needs for realtime user data queries made me search a little more for elasticsearch (because I already use it on other software parts).

Every user page interaction will query the user previous data, returning some statistics that will be used for site personalization (custom banner, etc).

So, the main question is: what database is better for this? A lot of inserts, a lot of queries on recent data and advanced queries for statistics. It is also important that the database need to scale fast and give a consistent performance when millions of data is loaded.